# Installing PyTorch on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, macos-big-sur

I am trying to figure out how to go about installing PyTorch on my computer which is a macOS Big Sur laptop (version 11.6.2). So far, I have installed Python 3.10.1 via the Python website, and pip 21.3.1 was installed along with it. At the moment, I’m stuck trying to figure out how to install PyTorch using pip?

I’m asking this question because I am partaking in a project that requires PyTorch and I need to install it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio
```

This command worked fine for me, you can find more information on the official website [here](https://pytorch.org/)

Answer (score 0):

There are (currently) no whl files available for python 3.10 on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/torch/#files), so the command

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio
```

won't work for you right now. Since you have only installed python now for this project, I would recommend that you simply uninstall python 3.10 and then download and install python 3.9.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply!